# Python: formatting dictionary having tuple as keys

Tags: python, dictionary, format, tuples

I want to format a dictionary for printing (Python 2.7.3), and the dictionary has tuples as keys. With other types of keys I can do

```
>>> coord = {'latitude': '37.24N', 'longitude': '-115.81W', 'altitude':100}
>>> 'Coordinates: {0[latitude]}, {0[longitude]}'.format(coord)
'Coordinates: 37.24N, -115.81W'
```

I tried the same but it does not work with tuple keys.

```
>>> a={(1,1):1.453, (1,2):2.967}
>>> a[1,1]
1.453
>>> 'Values: {0[1,1]}'.format(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#66>", line 1, in <module>
    'Values: {0[1,1]}'.format(a)
KeyError: '1,1'
```

Why? How I can refer to tuple keys in formatting string?

**FOLLOW UP**

It seems we can't (see answer below). As agf quickly pointed out, Python can't handle this (hope it will be implemented).
In the meantime, I managed to refer to tuple keys in format string with the following workaround:

```
my_tuple=(1,1)
b={str(x):a[x] for x in a} # converting tuple keys to string keys
('Values: {0[%s]}'%(str(my_tuple))).format(b) # using the tuple for formatting
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), `field_name` is described (emphasis mine):

> The `field_name` itself begins with an `arg_name` that is either a **number or a keyword**. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument. If the numerical arg_names in a format string are 0, 1, 2, ... in sequence, they can all be omitted (not just some) and the numbers 0, 1, 2, ... will be automatically inserted in that order. **Because `arg_name` is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings `'10'` or `':-]'`) within a format string**. The `arg_name` can be followed by any number of index or attribute expressions. An expression of the form `'.name'` selects the named attribute using `getattr()`, while **an expression of the form `'[index]'` does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`**.

The grammar describes `arg_name` as:

```
arg_name          ::=  [identifier | integer]
```

where `identifier` is:

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

So a `tuple` is not a valid `arg_name` as it is neither an `identifier` or an `integer`, and can't be an arbitrary dictionary key because string keys aren't quoted.

Comment: Your quotation says I can't use "arbitrary" string, but "some" strings can be used as dictionary keys, as in my 1st example. So what does "keyword" mean? Only a string that can not be interpreted as number? No tuples then? Pretty weird limitation though.

Comment: @mmj It really comes down to the fact that Python has to decide whether `1,1` means a `str`ing, `'1,1'` or a `tuple`, `(1, 1)`. It does the simpler thing, and assumes if it's not an integer, it's a string.